# Styling footnotes for markdown

Tags: css, markdown, footnotes

I've been using footnotes in markdown pages as mentioned [in this post](http://daringfireball.net/2005/07/footnotes) on DaringFireball, but I can't seem to figure out how to get them styled the way I want. Adding .footnotes {} to my style sheet allows me to style the footnote text, but I'm missing two things:

1. In Gruber's post, his footnote's backlink is given a style "a.footnoteBackLink," but my page simply produces "a href="link" rev="footnote". I don't know how to call this in CSS and I have no idea how I'd change it so that my markdown page outputs any differently. My backlink goes to a separate line, and I'd like to have it on the same line. Perhaps this is an issue with the markdown engine; I'm using Maruku (I think), and I could probably figure out how to change it if I knew which one I should use instead.
2. No matter what I put in the footnote brackets, the page outputs numbered footnotes. How can I tell it to use asterisks or other symbols? Most pages with footnotes will have only one or two, and symbols are generally correct when there are less than seven footnotes, so I'd like to do things proper.

I probably shouldn't even say this, but I've been teaching myself web development for the past couple of months and I absolutely could not have done it without SO. This is the first time I haven't found my answer here, so it's my first time asking. I love you don't get mad at me please.

Comment: You can reference those links in your CSS using the selector `a[rev="footnote"]`.

Comment: That doesn't seem to work- I tried making the text huge just to see if it did anything, and a quick "inspect element" on the page doesn't show that selector at all. I found one other mention of the issue on ikiwiki's github page, so it's possible the issue is my site generator.

Comment: "I've been teaching myself web development for the past couple of months and I absolutely could not have done it without SO." Upvoted.

Answer (score 1):

There is a great variety of conversion tools out there. Each may have a different way of handling this. I found [remarkable](https://github.com/jonschlinkert/remarkable) a good choice for your issue. It adds the class "footnote-item" to each footnote.

Check the [live demo](http://jonschlinkert.github.io/remarkable/demo/) and inspect the HTML Output.